# How do I know what service account is tied to which server?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I see notifications about actions being performed by `123456-compute@service-account` but how do I know what servers performed these actions? When I search 123456 in GCE I don't see any servers come up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gcloud tool to list service accounts assigned to compute instances:

```
gcloud --format='table(name,serviceAccounts.email)' compute instances list
```

The output would be something like that:

```
NAME        EMAIL
instance-1  [u'123456-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com']
instance-2  [u'234567-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com']
```

It can be that all instances run with the same service account. For example compute engine instances created using GCP console or gcloud tool have default compute engine service account assigned.
In this case service account wouldn't help in identifying which server performed an action.